# Extracting Private key from pkcs12 and text encryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, pkcs#12

I have .p12 file, I am extracting the private key using openssl, I have a password for extracting it.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

And after I get my private key, I'm trying to use that key for encryption:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyPair keyPair = readKeyPair(privateKey, "testpassword".toCharArray());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
        byte[] textEncrypted = cipher.doFinal("hello world".getBytes());
        System.out.println("encrypted: "+new String(textEncrypted));
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
        byte[] textDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);
        System.out.println("decrypted: "+new String(textDecrypted));
    }

    private static KeyPair readKeyPair(File privateKey, char[] keyPassword) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(privateKey);
        PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader, new DefaultPasswordFinder(keyPassword));
        try {
            return (KeyPair) r.readObject(); // this returns null
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException("The private key could not be decrypted", ex);
        } finally {
            r.close();
            fileReader.close();
        }
    }
```

**r.readObject();** returns null. But when I create a private key by myself by this command:

```
openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048
```

The above code works fine.

- How can I extract private key from p12 file properly?
- Or is there any way to use p12 file for encrypt/decrypt the text
  without extracting through command line?

*I know it is just [PKCS#12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF12) is just archaive file which stores keys.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with your code, but I have code that reads stuff from a key store. I read the file into a KeyStore instance and then access the key or entry as appropriate. Here are some of the relevant calls:

```
char[] password;
String alias;
java.security.KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
keyStore.load(inputStream, password);
java.security.PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password);
java.security.keystore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));
```

To find the alias of the entry you are interested in, I suggest using keytool (comes with JDK):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.pkcs12 -storetype pkcs12
```

You will be prompted for the keystore password and then get information like this:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: thealias
Creation date: Aug 30, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
[... lots of info about the certificates deleted ...]
```

Comment: Hi Rob thank you for your answer. I tried such way before. my keystore doesn't have any alias somehow. is there any way to figure out way. I have a certificate alongh with p12 file.

Comment: Added some details on listing the contents of the keystore, so perhaps you can find the alias that is on the entry that you are interested in.

Comment: It is showing me this: `Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries`, BTW, I have *.cer, file along with my .p12 file. is there something to do with it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't use openssl, so I don't know why you are not getting a keystore that Java thinks is pkcs12 and contains a key pair. The fact that keytool says there are no entries is consistent with your original Java code returning null. Perhaps you should try using keytool to create your keystore file (using `-storetype pkcs12` to ensure you know that it is a pkcs12 file).